# Accessing Volumes in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I want to access an external directory 'web-app' in my docker container.

Consider the directory structure below:

```
MyDcocker
   |-dockerFile
   |-web-app
        |-flask-web.py
```

I have the following lines in my dockerfile:

```
VOLUME ["web-app"]
# Run flask-web (API) file
CMD ["python3","web-app/flask-web.py"]
```

When running the image, I get the error:

python3: can't open file 'web-app/flask-web.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I believe the directory has not been mounted properly. How do I solve this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will write in Dockerfile how you build the container, not how container will interact with your host.

For mount a directory from your host in your container, you have 2 solutions :

with docker command line :

```
docker run -v $(pwd)/web-app:/var/lib/web-app/ dck-image-name
```

with docker-compose

```
version: '2'
services:
  myservice:
    image: dck-image-name
    volumes:
      - ./web-app:/var/lib/web-app/
```

Comment: Alternative: Copy the files to the image instead of mounting: `ADD webapp /var/webapp`

Comment: So I am assuming, the contents of web-app will now be accessible in: /var/lib/web-app/ (inside the container).
I have put: CMD ["python3","/var/lib/web-app//flask-web.py"] in my docker file. I still get the same error.

Comment: Could you edit your questions with your Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: And the result of 'ls -al /var/lib/web-app/'